# How do I publish multiple web site projects in the same solution to one folder?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, web

I want to keep multiple web site projects in one solution and I want to publish them all together in one folder. What are the steps to do that? Can I publish the whole solution? I am guessing the solution is only a container that is holding different web site projects. I want to publish all these small web site projects into one place and I want to use a single page for the authentication for the whole application. How can I publish these multiple web sites at one location? Do I have to manage web.config?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really need is a single web project (and I'd recommend web application projects rather than web "site" projects... but that's another topic).

If they all share common authentication and root folder, why separate them?

Comment: no i have seprate small projects right now , i want to put them together and use one authentication page for all of them

Answer (score 1):

You could use an MsBuild on NAnt build script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously consider merging the projects into 1, especially if they will be using the same authentication system. Once merged, you would be able to use inherited MasterPages to easily give each section it's own "look-and-feel", while still maintaining the site's style.