# How can I publish 2 dynamic web projects into same context root on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

These days I'm designing new version of my company's web application product. It's kind of a solution but has many variety because each customers want to have their own website.

It's not only a problem of changing view based on MVC pattern. Sometimes I need include 3rd party library only for the customer. I don't like adding customer-specific library to product project. Then I got an idea.

Let common part of project stay the original project, and extract customer-specific library or code to other new project. New project will be compiled well because it may have dependency on original common project. The original common project, of course, has no problem.

**Here is my question now.** I'll use maven so I can obtain WAR file from 2 different project for deployment. But how about *during development using Eclipse?* How can I publish 2 dynamic web projects into same context root?

---

When I typed title, stackoverflow suggested 2 interest similar questions: [Can multiple projects have the same context-root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468558/can-multiple-projects-have-the-same-context-root) & [How do I publish multiple web site projects in the same solution to one folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124355/how-do-i-publish-multiple-web-site-projects-in-the-same-solution-to-one-folder) but none of them are useful for me.

I'm waiting your kind advice.